# Why Is Everything That Should Be Clickable Suddenly Not Clickable On My HTML Page?

Tags: html, css

The buttons, text boxes, spinner, etc. were working and now they no longer do after closing the program and opening it again. Nothing that should be clickable is clickable anymore even though the code has not changed. The code also worked fine when someone else tested it. What could be the problem and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

*Had all of the code that wasn't working posted, but Stack Overflow didn't like how long my post was, so here's a link to it: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexRiley/k92j68nu/3/#&togetherjs=nySlrKCerr

```css
/* WHOLE PAGE */

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 2000px) {}

:root {
  --textColor1: burlywood;
  --textColor2: rgb(236, 221, 200);
  --textColor3: rgba(248, 82, 4, 0.808);
  --textColor4: rgb(243, 236, 229);
  --backgroundColor1: rgb(27, 11, 1);
}

html {
  background-color: rgb(166, 110, 78);
  min-width: 480px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}


/* HEADERS */

h1 {
  color: var(--textColor1);
  font-family: Agbalumo;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px var(--backgroundColor1);
}

h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Agbalumo;
  color: var(--textColor4);
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  color: var(--textColor3);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: light;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 17%;
  color: var(--textColor2);
}

h6 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* TEXT */

p {
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  border: 2px solid burlywood;
}

#header {
  top: 0;
}

#menu {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--textColor4);
  font-weight: bold;
}

span {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu-ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: var(--textColor1);
  margin-left: 15%
}

#promoAd,
#promoCode {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#author {
  color: rgb(51, 49, 49);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#liveStreamHeader {
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}

#checkOutStream {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}

#broughtToYou {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}


/* IMAGES AND VIDEOS */

#header-img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.coffeeImage {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#info {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/* Flexbox */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#deerImg,
#chipImg,
#foxImg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 150px;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#contactEmail {
  color: rgb(7, 7, 141);
  transition: color 0.15s;
}

#contactEmail:hover {
  color: blue;
}

#contactEmail:active {
  color: rgb(97, 140, 233);
}


/* DIVS, FORMS, AND FIELDSETS */


/* Form Elements */

legend {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-size: 13px;
}


/* Other Divs */

#promo {
  background-color: rgb(119, 243, 181);
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vidDiv {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}


/* Dark Brown Divs */

#orderDiv,
#newsletterDiv,
#reviewDiv {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor1);
  color: var(--textColor1);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid burlywood
}

#menuDiv {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor1);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#infoDiv {
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor1);
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 80px auto 20px auto;
  display: block;
  color: var(--textColor1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Contact */

#contactDiv {
  background-color: rgb(224, 198, 164);
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid var(--backgroundColor1);
}

#contact {
  color: black;
}


/* Input */

select {
  font-family: serif;
  color: gray;
  margin: 5px auto 5px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}

option {
  font-family: serif;
  color: black;
}

option:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}

input[type=number] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=tel] {
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Newsletter */

#newsletterEmail {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 10px auto;
}


/* How Did You Order? */

#onlineInStore {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Rating Slider */

#ratingDiv {
  margin: 20px auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#serviceRating {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#ratingValues {
  margin: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/* Text Area */

#reviewTextDiv {
  float: bottom;
  margin-top: 86px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#reviewText {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid burlywood;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#details {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* BUTTONS */


/* Navigation Buttons */

nav a,
.navButton {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: var(--textColor2);
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}

.navButton:hover {
  background-color: rgb(73, 30, 6);
}

.navButton:active {
  background-color: rgb(74, 47, 32);
}


/* Live Stream Button */

#liveButton {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(7, 90, 7);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: serif;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}

#liveButton:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#liveButton:active {
  background-color: rgb(80, 171, 80);
}


/* Submit Buttons */

#submit,
#newsletterSubmit,
#reviewSubmit {
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: rgb(3, 90, 3);
  color: var(--textColor4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35%;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}

#submit:hover,
#newsletterSubmit:hover,
#reviewSubmit:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#submit:active,
#newsletterSubmit:active,
#reviewSubmit:active {
  background-color: rgb(61, 170, 61);
}


/* Clear Buttons */

#orderClear,
#emailClear,
#reviewClear {
  font-family: serif;
  background-color: rgb(135, 9, 9);
  color: var(--textColor4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20%;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}

#orderClear:hover,
#emailClear:hover,
#reviewClear:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#orderClear:active,
#emailClear:active,
#reviewClear:active {
  background-color: rgb(235, 101, 101);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Agbalumo">



<!---HEADER--->
<header id="header">
  <h1>Caffeinated Critter Caf&eacute</h1>
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/squirrel-sitting-drink-coffee-cute-creative-kawaii-cartoon-mascot-logo_152710-1348.jpg" id="header-img" alt="caffeinated critter cafe logo - chipmunk holding a cup of coffee" />

  <!---NAVIGATION--->
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#info" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Info</button></a>
    <a href="#menu" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Menu</button></a>
    <a href="#live" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Live Stream</button></a>
    <a href="#form" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Order Online</button></a>
    <a href="#newsletter" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Newsletter</button></a>
    <a href="#review" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Leave A Review</button></a>
    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link"><button class="navButton">Contact</button></a>
  </nav>
</header>
<br>
<br>

<!---INFO--->
<div id="infoDiv">
  <h2 id="info">Info</h2>
  <p>
    Welcome to Caffeinated Critter Caf&eacute!
  </p>
  <p>
    We offer a relaxing woodland themed experience while you enjoy your favorite coffee drinks, pastries, and sounds of the forest.
  </p>
  <p>
    The kids will enjoy our child-friendly options as well as our forest-themed play place! For adults, we offer free WiFi and an assortment of caffeinated beverages. Stop by or order online today!
  </p>
</div>
<hr>

<!---PROMO--->
<div id="promo">
  <p id="promoAd">GET 15% OFF YOUR TOTAL TODAY WHEN YOU USE THIS PROMO CODE AT CHECKOUT!</p>
  <p>Code:</p>
  <p id="promoCode">ESPRESSO2023</p>
  <h6>*Promo code can be used only once per customer. Offer expires 12/31/2023.</h6>
</div>
<hr>
<!---VIDEO--->
<div class="vidDiv">
  <video height="100%" width="100%" controls="controls" id="video" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/vimeo/449623829/coffee-46989.mp4?width=1280&hash=f1016af9b0feba056c8acb43eeb2bec65a677c21" />
</div>
<hr>
<!---MENU--->
<div id="menuDiv">
  <h2 id="menu">Menu</h2>
  <ul id="menu-ul">
    <h3>Coffee</h3>
    <li>- Americano <span>$3.00</span></li>
    <h5>Espresso with water</h5>
    <li>- Cappuccino <span>$3.50</span></li>
    <h5>Espresso, steamed milk, and foam</h5>
    <li>- Macchiato <span>$3.50</span></li>
    <h5>Espresso topped with foam</h5>
    <li>- Latte <span>$3.50</span></li>
    <h5>Espresso with stemed milk, topped with foam</h5>
    <li>- Cold Brew <span>$4.00</span></li>
    <h5>Coffee brewed at room temperature for 24 hours</h5>
    <h3>Food</h3>
    <li>- Muffin<span>$2.00</span></li>
    <h5>Blueberry, Apple, or Chocolate Chip</h5>
    <li>- Croissant<span>$3.00</span></li>
    <h5>Plain or Chocolate</h5>
    <li>- Banana Bread<span>$2.00</span></li>
    <h5>With or Without Waluts</h5>
    <li>- Cookie<span>$1.50</span></li>
    <h5>Chocolate Chip or Sugar</h5>
    <h3>Kids</h3>
    <li>- Juice<span>$1.00</span></li>
    <h5>Apple, Orange, or Grape</h5>
    <li>- Milk<span>$1.50</span></li>
    <h5>Plain, Chocolate, or Strawberry</h5>
    <li>- Hot Chocolate<span>$2.00</span></li>
    <h5>With or Without Mini Marshmallows</h5>
    <h3>Add-Ons</h3>
    <li>- Extra Shot of Espresso<span>$0.50</span></li>
    <li>- Whipped Cream<span>$0.25</span></li>
    <li>- Cinnamon <span>$0.25</span></li>
    <li>- Extra Sugar <span>$0.25</span></li>
    <li>- Extra Milk or Cream <span>$0.50</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>

<h2 id="liveStreamHeader">Live Stream</h2>
<p id="checkOutStream">Check Out This Wildlife Live Stream!</p>
<h6 id="broughtToYou">Brought to you by Explore.org</h6>
<div class="vidDiv" id="live">
  <iframe width="702" height="394" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5e4lsEe4Vew" title="International Wolf Center North Camera powered by EXPLORE.org" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<a href="https://explore.org/livecams"><button id="liveButton">More Live Streams</button></a>
<hr>
<!---ORDER ONLINE--->
<div id="orderDiv">
  <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Order Online</legend>
      <div class="coffeImage">
        <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/020/002/842/original/coffee-cup-graphic-clipart-design-free-png.png" class="coffeeImage" alt="cup of coffee with a heart shape inside" />
      </div>
      <select>
        <option value="">Coffee</option>
        <option value="americano">Americano ----- $3.00</option>
        <option value="cappuccino">Cappuccino ----- $3.50</option>
        <option value="macchiato">Macchiato ----- $3.50</option>
        <option value="latte">Latte ----- $3.50</option>
        <option value="coldBrew">Cold Brew ----- $4.00</option>
      </select> <input type="number" name="quantity" id="coffee_quantity" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="coffee_quantity" placeholder="0" />
      <select>
        <option value="">Food</option>
        <option value="blueberryMuffin">Blueberry Muffin ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="appleMuffin">Apple Muffin ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="chocolateChip">Chocolate Chip Muffin ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="plainCroissant">Plain Croissant ----- $3.00</option>
        <option value="chocolateCroissant">Chocolate Croissant ----- $3.00</option>
        <option value="bananaBreadNuts">Banana Bread with Nuts ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="bananaBreadNoNuts">Banana Bread without Nuts ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="chocolateChipCookie">Chocolate Chip Cookie ----- $1.50</option>
        <option value="sugarCookie">Sugar Cookie ----- $1.50</option>
      </select> <input type="number" name="quantity" value="food_quantity" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="food_quantity" placeholder="0" />
      <select>
        <option value="">Kids Menu</option>
        <option value="appleJuice">Apple Juice ----- $1.00</option>
        <option value="orangeJuice">Orange Juice ----- $1.00</option>
        <option value="grapeJuice">Grape Juice ----- $1.00</option>
        <option value="plainMilk">Plain Milk ----- $1.50</option>
        <option value="chocolateMilk">Chocolate Milk ----- $1.50</option>
        <option value="strawberryMilk">Strawberry Milk ----- $1.50</option>
        <option value="hotChocolateMarshmallow">Hot Chocolate with Mini Marshmallows ----- $2.00</option>
        <option value="hotChocolateNoMarshmallow">Hot Chocolate without Marshmallows ----- $2.00</option>
      </select> <input type="number" name="quantity" value="kids_quantity" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="kids_quantity" placeholder="0" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Customer Info</legend>
      <label for="orderName">Name For Your Order: </label> <input type="text" placeholder="First and Last Name" id="orderName" />
      <label for="email">Email: </label> <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />
      <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number: </label> <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="(###)-###-####" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="orderClear" />
  </form>
</div>
<hr>

<!---NEWSLETTER FORM--->
<div id="newsletterDiv">
  <form id="newsletter">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Sign Up for Our Weekly Newsletter</legend>
      <p><strong>Receive emails about coupons, promotions, and new menu items!</strong></p>
      <label for="newsletterEmail">Email: </label>
      <input type="mail" id="newsletterEmail" placeholder="example@example.com" />
      <label for="newsletterName">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="newsletterName" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="newsletterSubmit" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="emailClear" />
  </form>
</div>
<hr>

<!---REVIEW FORM--->
<div id="reviewDiv">
  <form id="review">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Tell Us About Your Experience</legend>
      <select id="onlineInStore">
        <option value="">How Did You Order?</option>
        <option value="online">Online</option>
        <option value="inStore">In Store</option>
      </select>
      <div id="ratingDiv">
        <label for="serviceRating">How would you rate your service?</label>
        <p id="ratingValues">Awful <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="serviceRating" id="serviceRating" /> Great</p>
      </div>
      <div id="reviewTextDiv">
        <p id="details">Give Us The Details: </p>
        <textarea id="reviewText" placeholder="I enjoyed my experience because..."></textarea>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="reviewSubmit" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="reviewClear" />
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<!---FLEXBOX--->
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://fpdcc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/caldwell-woods-fawn-deer-jun14.jpg" alt="deer lying in the woods" id="deerImg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/TWCNews/Eastern_Chipmunk_RT_Images_ADJ_NC_0504" alt="chipmunk standing on a rock" id="chipImg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.natgeofe.com/k/6496b566-0510-4e92-84e8-7a0cf04aa505/red-fox-portrait_square.jpg" alt="fox standing on snow and looking at the camera" id="foxImg" />
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<!---CONTACT--->
<div id="contactDiv">
  <h2 id="contact">Contact Us</h2>
  <p><b>Email: </b></p>
  <a href="mailto: customerservice@crittercafe.com" id="contactEmail">customerservice@crittercafe.com</a>
  <p><b>Call: </b></p>
  <p>843-369-2468</p>
</div>
<hr>

<footer>
  <h6 id="author">Alex Riley</h6>
</footer>
```

I don't know what's up with the white background. That doesn't happen when I run the code on any other platform.

I tried:

- Copying and pasting my code from the website that I was using and into VS Code to see if it would work when running outside of the website. I expected it to work and thought that my issue was possibly a problem with the website itself, but it did not end up working.
- Checking to make sure that all of my style rules have opening and closing curly brackets.
- Making sure that my syntax was correct.

Comment: If your code is too long to post on stackoverflow you could post a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or any other online code sharing platform so we could get a better look at your problem.

Comment: Oh cool, I'll try that!

Comment: Made a jsfiddle account and added a link to the code to my original post

Comment: Does the jsfiddle exhibit the problem? When I run it, the buttons are working fine. The white background is being added by jsfiddle, so don't worry about that.

Comment: yes, jsfiddle is exhibiting the same problem on my end. The navigation buttons at the top of the screen work, but none of the others do

Comment: Give `#nav-bar` a background color, and you will see what the issue is.

Comment: FYI - The `footer` is incorrectly located beyond the closing `body` tag. That has been corrected in the snippet

Comment: It looks like you can simply remove `bottom: 0;` from the `#nav-bar` css rule. Learn to use the console and the tools therein, in this case specifically the style inspector. In Google Chrome it is easy to isolate offending style rules

Comment: @katsucurry: it's fine for a question to contain a link to a JS Fiddle, but we should be careful not to recommend this on its own. Per policy, questions must contain the code (or a sample of it) in the post itself. This is so that we do not have to delete the question if the remote code sample is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#nav-bar` is fixed and is sitting on top of the page and everything else is underneath it. You've got `bottom: 0` on the `#nav-bar` this allowing it to take up the entire height of the view port. Remove the `bottom: 0` from `#nav-bar`.

Comment: This worked, thank you!